Are Centralized Sequencer really Centralized?
What actually does centralized means?
Does it mean, the work of the sequencer is done entirely by a centralized server chosen by the operator? Or does it mean, the sequencer is chosen from one of the validators who stake some ETH to be chosen as a sequencer and perform the duty of sequencer all by itself?
A video from Chicago Meetup 2020 https://youtu.be/e8TQ4oQ0tLw?si=gwuoSkzO_dA9xyB_&t=597 says the later one.

Sorry, not going to check the video, but there is no absolute correct answer for "what is centralized". It depends on the context and for some people it means a bit different things.
I would say being centralized means there is a single point of failure in a system: a server or a service - or some human resource.
If a sequencer is chosen from a set of valid sequencers, it sounds better than a fully centralized option where there is just one sequencer. But, of course, this depends - maybe the choosing process is corrupt, incorrect or centralized itself.
